# display and save only packet captured by filter

Tags: wireshark

how can I let wireshark display only packets that are captured by a filter I don't want to have all packets, this takes a large memory space ?

Comment: Off topic for [so], may belong on [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the menu group Capture, you can set a capture filter.  Capture filters use the same syntax as tcpdump; the syntax is different from the syntax for capture filters.

Comment: @Guy Harris thanks for putting me straight on this.

Comment: Thanks, here a tutorial about its syntax : http://openmaniak.com/tcpdump.php